# How to save pyspark Dataframe to downloadable excel file in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

pandasDf=REV_COMP_DF.toPandas()
pandasDf.to_excel('/tmp/revenue.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter',header=True)
dbutils.fs.mv('file:/tmp/revenue.xlsx','RESULT/revenue.xlsx')
test=pd.read_excel('/dbfs/RESULT/revenue.xlsx')
```

Tried the above code, but it's creating file in dbfs, and we cannot download the file locally.

Is there any way to create downloadable excel files from pyspark dataframes in databricks.

Comment: One suggestion I have is that you can try using the `dbutils.fs.cp` command instead of `dbutils.fs.mv`. It will keep a copy in the dbfs location even if something goes wrong, you still have a copy of it lying in the original location.

Answer (score 0):

To download the excel file you can do a display of the `test` dataframe in the Databricks notebook interface using

```
display(test)
```

There should be a download icon something as follows:
[image]

Refer this [SO qn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620050/how-to-export-data-from-a-dataframe-to-a-file-databricks) as well.